# How to add a json string as a app setting value in config file

Tags: c#, json, app-config

I have a requirement whereby I need to fetch a set of jsons before making a API call.
I am planning to add these json strings in app.config as shown below

```
 <add key="Jsons" value="{""Id"":""25"",""Name"":""Value-1""}"/>
```

However adding this results in a compilation error "Missing whitespace" at the start of the value.
Please let me know if i am missing something. 
I dont want to create a separate text file to read jsons from. Thats why i decided to use app.config itself

Comment: If I dont use "" i get multiple errors

Comment: Should be formated like {"Id":"25", "Name":"Value-1"}

Comment: That gives formating errors

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your quotes are not correctly formatted. 
Can you try this:

`<add key="Jsons" value='{"Id":"25","Name":"Value-1"}'/>`

Comment: Wow, that looks a lot like my comment??

Comment: @Fergus Why the down vote? I didn't saw your comment, and when I looked at it now, mine was more complete :)

Comment: @ShaijuJanardhanan, great, don't forget to mark it as the answer if it is :)

Comment: @Fergus but i couldnt figure out the issue from your answer since i had tried with proper formatting too. The single quote was what i was not using

Comment: Awesome, that's the beauty of SO.

Answer (score 2):

An `app.config` is still XML! You need to use the XML escape sequence for quotes.

```
<add key="Jsons" value="{&quot;Id&quot;:&quot;25&quot;,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Value-1&quot;}"/>
```

Comment: That looks a lot verbose. The accepted answer actually works

Answer (score 0):

I see two choices here:

1. Use "\" to escape:

   ```
     <add key="Jsons" value="{\"Id\":\"25\",\"Name\":\"Value-1\"}"/>
   ```
2. Use single quote:

   ```
   <add key="Jsons" value="{'Id':'25','Name':'Value-1'}"/>
   ```

Comment: Though many parsers may allow it, using single quotes in JSON is technically invalid.

Comment: It is not a valid JSON